# What are "Exact compiler arguments" for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, terminology

I'm a mostly self-taught programmer, and recently applied for a computation-heavy internship.

As part of the selection process, I was sent, from some recruiter in a distant city, a programming challenge to complete in Python (I used Python 3). 
The program accepts a couple of positional arguments, and writes its results to a file.

I need to submit "source code and exact compiler arguments used to compile." I'm looking for enlightenment on what the last bit means.

From Python3 idle, if programFile contains only function definitions, I can do

```
>>> import programFile
>>> function(arg1,arg2)
```

to get the output. Or if I add an executable statement to the programFile, I can do `python programFile.py` from the command line to get the output. I don't know if one of these is the compiler argument, or if I need something else which would only compile the code.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recruiter is using generic terminology that doesn't apply to Python. No compiler is used, so no compiler arguments are required either.

Send the source file and minimum Python version requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language you don't need to compile the python file(.py) in order to execute it.

I think the recruiter is using the same message for every language in their program.

I would only send the source code, document it on how to use it and you will be good.